# How to determine total number of rows affected in a transaction prior to commit in postgresql?

Tags: database, postgresql, transactions

I have a usecase in which I will be executing an arbitrarily sized group of unknown SQL/pglpsql queries given to me by the user. I am writing a Python script that will execute those queries in one transaction. Now, in the transaction, prior to commit, I would like to be able to see how many rows are touched CUMULATIVELY so that if that number is over a fixed constant threshold, I can roll the transaction back. I am using PostreSQL database. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the below function might help :-

```
    create or replace function get_rows_affected() returns void as $$ declare
        v_count number; 
        begin
        v_count := 0;

            update table_name set col_name = '504';
            GET DIAGNOSTICS v_count = ROW_COUNT;

            if v_count > 2 then
               RAISE EXCEPTION 'more than one row affected --> %', v_count; 

            end if;
     end; 
     $$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: @ion20 - Could you please provide the feedback if it worked for you or not?

Comment: in my use case, I am going to be receiving a variety of differently-formed SQL statements including plpgsql functions to run. Can I encapsulate all of that inside your function? E.g. what is instead of `update table_name set col_name = '504';` I have ```update...
DO $zzz$
....
$zzz$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;``` Does this still work? Is such encapsulation even allowed?

Comment: So if any of your sql statement are found crossing the update limit, do you want all your previous transaction to be rolledback or you want to roll back that particular transaction? Do you want same limit to set for all of  your transactions? Please describe your  problem in detail

Comment: Updated body. Does it make more sense now?